Existing tools for specific k-mer-based searches
Currently I'm working with Foldseek and its 3Di-based alphabet, and I wanted to search and isolate proteins within my database that contained a similar k-mer to an unique k-mer I had found. I do not see any present way to do this through foldseek, having looked through the github and wiki extensively.
I was wondering if there are any existing bioinformatics tools (and ones that don't specifically focus on nucleotide sequences) that can search for a specific k-mer along a database? Additionally, do any of these tools work with a substitution matrix opposed to direct sequence coverage? If so, any way to customize the substitution matrix to the specific sequence language I'm using?
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I might be missing something, but this is basically BLASTP. Is there a reason that you don't want to use the standard alignment based homology searches against a database?
You will of course want to adjust word size and E value thresholds accordingly for what is presumably a short input. They have a few substitution matrix options, though I'm not sure that you can be fully custom without modifying the source code.
